# Как нормально добавить дополнительные собственные кнопки в Dialog в libGdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

Не получается нормально добавить собственные кнопки в Dialog.Не получается эти кнопки равномерно распределить по ширине.

```
    TextButton b_production=new TextButton("Production",skin);
    b_production.setWidth((float) (getWidth()*0.4));
    getButtonTable().add(b_production).growY().width((float) (getWidth()*0.4));
    TextButton b_info=new TextButton("Information",skin);
    b_info.setWidth((float) (getWidth()*0.4));
    getButtonTable().add(b_info).growX().width((float) (getWidth()*0.4));
    button("X",0);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]